# What happens if a person drinks the juice made from two Devil Fruits?

Tags: one-piece

Suppose a person takes two Devil Fruits and extracts the juice from them, and then mixes the juices and then drinks. What will happen?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Devil Fruit wikipedia page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit):

> Only one bite is needed for the user to gain the power of a Devil Fruit, after which the Devil Fruit becomes a simple, useless, disgusting fruit. Swallowing the fruit whole, as Buggy did, has the same effect,[8] Peeling off the skin and eating it piece by piece, such as Kaku and Kalifa did, also works. After ingesting the fruit, the powers within affect the eater's lineage factor.

So basically the method the fruit is eaten does not matter, whether it be eating it piece by piece, as a whole or as a juice. It is the first bite or sip that is important, because after that the fruit becomes useless. So what this means is that in OP's question the person would basically have eaten two fruits.

> One rumor, as recounted by Jabra, is that Devil Fruits house actual devils that will fight when placed in proximity of one another. The resulting battle would destroy the users' bodies. Nevertheless, Blueno contradicted this claim, stating that Grand Line scientists have noted that the phenomenon of one's body destroying itself only occurs when one consumes two Devil Fruits.[18]

So according to Grand Line scientists, a person that would eat or drink two Devil Fruits **would die**.

Comment: I am wondering why you posted this as a separate answer rather than edited your original answer. if it is because your original one as your own opinion in it you could just state that in your answer

Comment: Because deleting and replacing the complete content of an answer wouldn't be considered an 'edit' anymore, would it? It also wouldn't be correct to the upvoter.

Comment: @Memor-X I'll grant that it's a little bit weird to have multiple answers by the same user on this site, but this is basically the same idea as posting multiple answers with different methodologies on [so] - if they are different, correct approaches of answering the question, I think it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Devil Fruit wikipedia page](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit):

> The Devil Fruit, when consumed, gives the consumer a power or special trait, which they will immediately become aware of

**In my opinion** this means that only when the fruit is **completely** consumed, that the Sea Devil is incarnated in the consumer's body and not any sooner. We can also see that the Sea Devil is not yet present in the Devil Fruit at Enies Lobby, where two Devil Fruits were near each other and nothing happened. Therefore if a person would drink the juice made of two devil fruits, he would only be wasting two Devil Fruits and make them useless. After he dies two half Devil Fruits would be incarnated somewhere.

I don't think Mister Oda ever mentioned what would happen if only part of a Devil fruit was eaten. Therefore this is just **my opinion** on this.

Comment: If I remember correctly chopper did not eat his fruit alone. He was just the first to take a bite from it. Which would mean 1 bite would be enougn.

Comment: One bite is definitely enough. I think it was stated by Oda-sensei before, but I can't remember when.

Comment: I just read the wiki completely and you are right, one bite is enough. I'll add another, correct answer.

Comment: To be honest, if one bite would be enough, then what's the point of eating the whole damn thing?